# Insert data to table in VB but no show in table

Tags: sql, vb.net

Here is my code. There are no errors being shown. I insert into the data table, but the data is not showing in the table. Can anyone solve this issue?.

```
Public Class Form11

    Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click

        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=loginUser.mdb;")
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Staff]", connection)

        command.Connection.Open()
        Dim count As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(command.ExecuteScalar())
        command.Connection.Close()
        count = count + 1
        MsgBox(count)

        Dim command1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Staff ([ID], [username], [password]) VALUES (@id,@user,@pass)", connection)

        With command1.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@id", count)
            .AddWithValue("@user", txtUsername.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@pass", txtPassword.Text)
        End With
        Using connection
            command1.Connection.Open()
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        command1.Connection.Close()
        MsgBox("Added")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Side-Note: You are closing an already closed connection. Note that the `Using`-statement disposes objects and `Connection.Dispose` calls `Close`. So you don't need to close a connection with the using-statement. But this does not cause an exception.

Comment: Do you get message box for  MsgBox(count) and MsgBox("Added")?

Comment: just add `Dim testData As String
            command1.CommandText = "select username where id = "& count&" "
            testData = cmd.ExecuteScalar`  before ` command1.Connection.Close()` and check `testData` getting any value

Comment: A) Using `Count` for an ID will eventually fail; use an AutoIncrement column B) Do not store passwords, hash them C) *How* are you determining the data is not added?

Comment: I think the combination of `Dim` and `Using` with the same variable name (connection) is causing the problem. Try either completely removing the `Using connection`/`End Using` lines (but not the code between them), or else delete the `Using connection` line and change `Dim connection As New...` to `Using connection As New...` and see if that gets it working.